# How do you run multiple unique instances of debounce at the same time?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, debouncing

I'm using [debounce](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debounce) (but am willing to use another module) with MongoDB [change streams](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/changeStreams/) to prevent a function from being called multiple times when there are many updates to the DB at once.  It works great except for when there are multiple users making changes to the DB, then debounce is only called on the last change.

I need a way to pass an `id` value to debounce so that there can be multiple versions running at the same time.

This is what is currently happening:

```
debounce(()=>console.log("ID A"), 500); // debounce is called for ID A
debounce(()=>console.log("ID B"), 500); // debounce is called for ID B
debounce(()=>console.log("ID B"), 500); // debounce is called for ID B

// output:
ID B // "ID A" is never returned because it is replaced by "ID B"
```

This is what I'm wanting to do:

```
debounce("ID A", ()=>console.log("ID A"), 500); // debounce is called for ID A
debounce("ID B", ()=>console.log("ID B"), 500); // debounce is called for ID B
debounce("ID B", ()=>console.log("ID B"), 500); // debounce is called for ID B

// output:
ID A
ID B
```

Does that make sense?  How can I implement that?

##### Example code

```
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
}

const debouncePool = {};
function debounceById(id) {
    console.log(`debounceById(${id})`);
    if (!debouncePool[id]) {
        debouncePool[id] = debounce(() => {
            console.log(id);
        }, 100);
    }
    debouncePool[id]();
}

debounceById("123");
await sleep(150);
debounceById("123");
debounceById("AAA");
debounceById("123");

// Output:
debounceById(123)
123
debounceById(123)
debounceById(AAA)
debounceById(123)
123 // AAA should return first
AAA // 123 should return second
```

it should be:

```
// Output:
debounceById(123)
123
debounceById(123)
debounceById(AAA)
debounceById(123)
AAA
123
```

Comment: debounce is a singleton by design. It's purpose is to run the last function passed within the timeframe. It's just 1 page: https://github.com/component/debounce/blob/master/index.js  Please fork or just copy-paste  and add whatever logic you need. It's just a timer for deferred invocation of the function.  Be mindful how many timers you have in a single nodejs process tho.  If there are a lot of concurrent updates, or any blocking code within the function, you may need to check nodejs timers internals https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/timers.js

Answer (score 1):

I switched to using [just-debounce-it](https://www.npmjs.com/package/just-debounce-it) and it works great now:

```
import debounce from "just-debounce-it";

function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
}

const debouncePool = {};
function debounceById(id) {
    console.log(`debounceById(${id})`);
    if (!debouncePool[id]) {
        debouncePool[id] = debounce(() => {
            console.log(id);
        }, 100);
    }
    debouncePool[id]();
}

debounceById("123");
await sleep(150);
debounceById("123");
debounceById("AAA");
debounceById("123");

//
// Output:
//
debounceById(123)
123
debounceById(123)
debounceById(AAA)
debounceById(123)
AAA
123
```